# ionic socket.io doesn't emit from an app

Tags: node.js, cordova, sockets, ionic-framework, socket.io

I hosted my app and has port 1000 for socket. I check the network tab things are running fine. **But I can't emit from my ionic app.**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','angular-jwt','btford.socket-io','angularMoment'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,socket) {

  socket.on('connect', function(data) {
    });

    socket.emit('something',data);

})

.factory('socket',function(socketFactory){
    if (!window.cordova) {
      var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:1000'); //this work
    } else {
      var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://example.com:1000'); //this don't when I run my app in a real device
    }



    mySocket = socketFactory({
      ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    return mySocket;
});
```

The strange thing is I'm able to emit when I'm in localhost, running my app through ionic serve in browser.

I've look into cors and also do

`<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />`

in my config.xml of my ionic app.

Those doesn't solve my problem. I also consulted digitalocean about my ngix's firewall, they said that wouldn't block websocket.

I've also consult helps from ionic, they suspect it's cordova issue.

Comment: first check if you can load any network resource, for connectivity

Comment: `$http.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/one/two")
  .then(function(response) {
      if(response.data.one === "two")
          alert("internet working");
  });`
Check if the alert fires!